# Roll with "punches""to get to what's real"

Tags: slang, lyrics

Listening to [**Van Halen's Jump**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwYN7mTi6HM), I have a problem.

Verse 1 has

> I get up and nothing gets me down
> You got it tough, I've seen the toughest around
> And I know, baby, just how you feel
> You gotta roll with **the punches to get to what's real**

If the line were "rolling with someone + etc", I would be fine, but I'm having a problem to get the meaning of "rolling with punches to get to what's real".

This [Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Punch) has many entries and explanations but no definitions do fit with the line.

Am I mishearing but instead they are saying "bunches"? No?

Thank you for helping me out for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom is [“roll with the punches”](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=roll%20with%20the%20punches):

> **roll with the punches**
>
> when things dont go your way and you adapt to the changes and keep moving ahead instead of flipin out
>
> *Nothing ever goes my way so i just roll with the punches*